# setMethod in S4 - how to define a method that doesn't need the object as an argument?

Tags: r, r-s4

In R with S4 classes, I define a method to assign two values to an object:

```
setGeneric("setValues", function(object, x, y) {
    standardGeneric("setValues")
})

setMethod(f = "setValues", signature = "chart", definition = function(object, x, y) {
    object@x <- x
    object@y <- y
    return(object)
})
```

and then use it as follows

```
obj <- setValues(obj, "value_X", "value_Y")
```

But, this means that I have to write `obj` as an argument to the function all the time.

***Is it possible to define a method in S4 that could be used without the object itself as an argument?***

For example:

```
obj <- setValues("value_X", "value_Y")
```

I am very grateful for any kind of suggestions! :)

Comment: Maybe you're looking for replacement methods, `setGeneric("values<-", function(object, ..., value) standardGeneric("values<-"); setReplaceMethod("values", c("chart", "character"), function(object, ..., value) { object@x <- value; object })` and then `values(obj) <- "value_X"` or a variant where `value` is a (named) list?

Comment: I think I'm missing something: how could you dispatch on something that isn't an argument to the generic function?

Comment: @MartinMorgan I was hoping for something similar to `"values<-"`, `values(obj) <- list(x = "value_X", y = "value_Y")`. So I thought (without really having any knowledge about S4 classes), that it would work with `"<-values"` in some way.

Comment: @hadley I think I'm missing knowledge on how S4 works. Perhaps my question should rather have been: what is the most user-friendly version of setValues that is possible to define in S4? E.g. `obj <- setValues(obj, "value_X", "value_Y")`, `obj$setValues("value_X", "value_Y")`, `obj <- obj + setValues("value_X", "value_Y")` ...

Comment: A bit of background to my question might be relevant; I want to write a package that can generate Highcharts JS graphs from R, so therefore I prefer that my functions looks similar to their [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#object-Chart), e.g. `setTitle(Object title, object subtitle)`. Perhaps, I should rather adjust the style more towards `ggplot2`? I am not only new to S4, but also on figuring out how to write user-friendly functions, so I am thankful for all your advices :) (OT: @hadley do you know if there are any progress on getting D3 to R?)

Comment: You may also want to look at reference classes aka r5. Either of those styles is possible. I'd say the first is most r like